# Applying a specific function to replace value of column based on criteria from another column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I am looking to do:

```
Dataframe before: 
       name         value    apply_f
0      SEBASTIEN    9        false
1      JOHN         4        false
2      JENNY        np.inf   true

Apply function f: len(df['name']) to columns 'value' only if columns 'apply_f' == True 

Dataframe after: 
       name       value    apply_f
0      SEBASTIEN  9        False
1      JOHN       4        False
2      JENNY      5        True
```

Here's what I currently have:

```
from pandas import *
from numpy import *

df = DataFrame( { "name":  ['SEBASTIEN', 'JOHN', 'JENNY'] , 
                  "value": [9, 4, np.inf] , 
                  "apply_f":  [False,False,True]} )

def f(x):
    return len(x)

df['value'] = df[df['apply_f'] == True]['name'].apply(f)
```

but result is not what I was expecting:

```
    apply_f    name         value
0   False      SEBASTIEN    NaN
1   False      JOHN         NaN
2    True      JENNY        5
```

The column replaces the initial values with NaN

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfectly clear,  it helps me to understand my faults !! i will give a try to 'numpy where' solution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it overwrites is because the indexing on the left hand side is defaulting to the entire dataframe, if you apply the mask to the left hand also using `loc` then it only affects those rows where the condition is met:

```
In [272]:

df.loc[df['apply_f'] == True, 'value'] = df[df['apply_f'] == True]['name'].apply(lambda row: f(row))
df
Out[272]:
  apply_f       name  value
0   False  SEBASTIEN      9
1   False       JOHN      4
2    True      JENNY      5
```

The use of `loc` in the above is because say I used the same boolean mask semantics this may or may not work and will raised an error in the latest pandas versions:

```
In[274]:
df[df['apply_f'] == True]['value'] = df[df['apply_f'] == True]['name'].apply(lambda row: f(row))
df
-c:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
Out[274]:
  apply_f       name     value
0   False  SEBASTIEN  9.000000
1   False       JOHN  4.000000
2    True      JENNY       inf
```

For what you are doing it would be more concise and readable to use numpy `where`:

```
In [279]:

df['value'] = np.where(df['apply_f']==True, len(df['name']), df['value'])
df
Out[279]:
  apply_f       name  value
0   False  SEBASTIEN      9
1   False       JOHN      4
2    True      JENNY      3
```

I understand that your example is to demonstrate an issue but you can also use `where` for certain situations.